# play m4a stream on iOs

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to play an iTunes sample within my app, I can get a URL preview like this:
http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/084/Music/2a/10/84/mzm.elnwknga.aac.p.m4a
How can I play it in the app? Should I use an AVPlayer?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use AVPlayer.  It has a handy initWithURL: method that you can use to pass that url to.  Then you just call [player play];